# When Animal Companion is multi-classed, does Command come with it?

Tags: dungeon-world, ranger

In my ongoing campaign of Dungeon World, a Bard chose to multi-class a skill, *Animal Companion* from the Ranger class. (Now, I suspect the bulk of my question depends upon a misunderstanding of how to handle such a companion, but let's leave that for another question.) This skill, *Animal Companion*, seems pretty tightly coupled with *Command*. When this Bard chose *Animal Companion*, should she have gained *Command* as well? Or is she limited to non-Command-based use of her new Raven companion?

This confusion is related to learning a Cleric spell as a multi-class move and then getting (or not getting?) the ability to Commune to re-memorize it daily.

Comment: Doh! Sorry. I cannot believe I missed that.

Comment: *I* can't believe I did too — I forgot that Q&A existed! When I saw this one I went looking for one about spellbooks instead just to link to it in an answer I was writing, and rediscovered that one in the process and gave myself a “d'oh!” moment. So +1 for a good question anyway.